# ng-repeat of input text not populating ng-model in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

Pretty new to Angular, I have an ng-repeat, that shows severl input boxes, each should have their own ng-model name, but the ng-repeat does not populate the ng-model with the name, and crashes if I try to build the watcher {{ }} around it (i.e. ng-model="{{data.id}}

My app.js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
         dataSet: null,
           inputs: [
           {id: 'data1', name: 'Option A', type:'input', preFill:"no.A"},
           {id: 'data2', name: 'Option B', type:'input', preFill:"no.B"},
           {id: 'data3', name: 'Option C', type:'input', preFill:"no.C"}
          ],
       };
     }]).directive('formPanel', function() { 
          return {
             restrict: 'E',
             scope: {
                 info: '='
             },
             template: '<div ng-controller="ExampleController"><form name="myForm">'+
             '<label for="{{option.name}}" ng-repeat="option in data.inputs"><br />'+
             'Input {{option.name}}:'+
             '<input ng-model="option.id" id="{{option.id}}" name="{{option.name}}" '+
             'type="{{option.type}}" class="form-control">'+
             ' </label></form><hr>'+
             '<span>data: = {{ data1}} , {{data2}}, {{data3}}.</span><br/>'+
             '</div>' };
   });
})
```

and the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="app" >
<form-panel info="data"></form-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

I Tried in this Plunker: [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tg0NTF1ZYmeme9FNRa2r?p=preview)

So as you can see, the ng-model is not bound(?) and probably for the same reason, the $scope name is appearing instead inside the input as data, instead of as the name of the data to be bound to.

i.e. should read ng-model="data1", but instead reads as ng-model="option.id"

Comment: Just to Clarify, The usage of ng-Controller in the template was just to make it easier to post in here, rather than several files. The expected output is data = no.A, no.B, no.C, where the data comes from the 3 input boxes.

Comment: So, after reading about track by, $compile, $link.. none of which seem to directly addresss my problem, but suggest that I'm just not understanding it.. I've had to write out the "<form Panels> by hand.. all 300+ of them.. to be able to access each and every input field to see the data .. FML.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should attach the controller to the app, just declaring it won't do.

You can do this by adding the attribute ng-controller="ExpampleController", or adding the controller to the directive:

```
restrict: 'E',
controller: 'ExampleController'
template:...
```

But if you add it to the directive, you just need to place the element `<form-panel>` and you don't have to pass it any info.

In addition, you can't interpolate ng-model="{{someData}}" as the expression is already evaluated without the curly braces

Comment: I don't understand how you think the controller is not already attached, are you saying its bad syntactically to put it in the template? when I put it outside in the html, it doesn't work at all. When I put it into the directive as you suggested, it stops working altogether. So that's a _fail_.

The real question is what you stated in your last sentence, ng-model needs to be the name of the $scope, so I pass it in as 'option.id' but it doesn't arrive as whats IN option.id, but as a string "option.id"

Comment: what do you mean "stop working alltogether"? what error does appear?

Comment: Sorry Kobi for the delay. I edited the plunker, and it stopped, but failed to see that my plunker was edited from another page. Moving the controller from the template to the directive makes no changes, so its not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the HTML code below:

```
<div>
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="{{option.name}}" ng-repeat="option in data.inputs"><br /> 
      Input {{option.name}}:
      <input ng-model="option.id" id="{{option.id}}" name="{{option.name}}"
        type="{{option.type}}" class="form-control"
        placeholder="{{ option.preFill }}">
    </label>
  </form>
  <hr>
 <tt>data: = {{ data.inputs[0].id }} , {{data.inputs[1].id}}, {{data.inputs[2].id}}.</tt><br/>
</div>
```

Have modified the code and you can find it in [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UeHJ29dL7hzrfJ6Dtp39?p=preview)

Comment: I checked.. but you've done nothing, the data fields in

<span>data: = {{ data1}} , {{data2}}, {{data3}}.</span><br/>

Comment: Could you check that now? I had not saved the plunker html.

Comment: Ahh I see what you've done, While its a nice workaround, the point is to access $scope.data1 as its the name of the data. I can work with what you've given me, should I mark it as the answer? The more correct answer would be to use $scope.data1 as its a location for incoming and outgoing data.. may as well use a document.getElementById('data1') if I'm not going to use two-way binding. let alone looking for data.inputs[0].id

Comment: So, I tried playing with what you gave me, to try and access data1.. no success.. I did seem to access it by creating a form element around it, Angular stores form data, so that sorta works..

http://plnkr.co/edit/qXupu4I4vWzMO7Sny02l?p=preview

but now I just need to 'get' all the form datas and put them INTO the data locations data1, data2 etc.. rather than just having them go directly in a.k.a. 2-way binding.